# CSS: Auto resize div to fit container width

Tags: css

I have two `<div>`: **left** and **contents**. These two are inside **wrapper** div that has `min-width:960px;`. **left** has fixed width, but I want to make content flexible with min width of **700px** and if screen is wider, stick it to the right bound of screen.
[image: screenshot]

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper
{
    min-width:960px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#left
{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:antiquewhite;
    margin-left:10px;
}
#content
{
    min-width:700px;
    margin-left:10px;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    background-color:AppWorkspace;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zvt2j/

Comment: duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051768/justify-divs-with-css-to-fill-width-of-parent-container

Comment: Just add `float:right;` to your `#content` div :)

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/LayoutGala32.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can `overflow:hidden` to your `#content`. Write like this:

```
#content
{
    min-width:700px;
    margin-left:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:AppWorkspace;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Zvt2j/1/

Answer (score 5):

You could use css3 flexible box, it would go like this:

First your wrapper is wrapping a lot of things so you need a wrapper just for the 2 horizontal floated boxes:

```
 <div id="hor-box"> 
    <div id="left">
        left
      </div>
    <div id="content">
       content
    </div>
</div>
```

And your css3 should be:

```
#hor-box{   
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;

 -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
 box-orient: horizontal; 
 -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;

}  
#left   {
      width:200px;
      background-color:antiquewhite;
      margin-left:10px;

     -webkit-box-flex: 0;
     -moz-box-flex: 0;
     box-flex: 0;  
}  
#content   {
      min-width:700px;
      margin-left:10px;
      background-color:AppWorkspace;

     -webkit-box-flex: 1;
     -moz-box-flex: 1;
      box-flex: 1; 
}
```

Comment: It's great for CSS3 supported browsers.

Answer (score 2):

```
#wrapper
{
    min-width:960px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position-relative;
}
#left
{
    width:200px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:antiquewhite;
    margin-left:10px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#content
{
    padding-left:210px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:AppWorkspace;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

If you need the whitespace on the right of `#left`, then add a `border-right: 10px solid #FFF;` to `#left` and add `10px` to the `padding-left` in `#content`

Answer (score 1):

[CSS auto-fit container between float:left & float:right divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858438/css-auto-fit-container-between-floatleft-floatright-divs?rq=1) solved my problem, thanks for your comments.

```
#left
{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:antiquewhite;
    margin-left:10px;
}
#content
{
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:10px;
    background-color:AppWorkspace;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zvt2j/2/) and here is CSS changes you need to do:

```
#content
{
    min-width:700px;
    margin-right: -210px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:AppWorkspace;
}
```