# Resizing content with different screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a single page website. I have a different container for each section which has a height of 100vh so the container resizes for different screens but the content does not which makes the website go all awry on small screens. How do I make the content resize as well with the container.

Comment: What content do you have inside? Perhaps you should provide an example.

Comment: Can you provide some example code? How do you expect the content to resize when the container gets smaller? Do you expect it to be clipped and then scroll (e.g.`overflow`); do you expect it to scale down in size; do you expect it to change layout; etc.?

Comment: I would recommend using a responsive framework like Bootstrap CSS or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <style>
     .resizer{
        min-width:700px;
        margin-left:10px;
        overflow:hidden;
      }
    </style>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <div class='resizer'>
       YOUR CONTENT goes here
    </div>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

You may also want to look at [CSS: Auto resize div to fit container width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319097/css-auto-resize-div-to-fit-container-width)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing you could do is go for a HTML5 responsive framework such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or use CSS media queries like shown [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) (or see below for quick example). Other than that it would probably involve javascript with similar end result to the aforementioned two ways.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
     }
}
```